# Get Runnable objects I scheduled using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor when using shutdownNow() method

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I'm using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(Runnable,int,TimeUnit) to schedule some objects of a class that implements Runnable.

At some point in time, my application is then shutting down, and I use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow%28%29). According to the documentation it returns a list of ScheduledFuture's.

What I really want to do is get a hold of the object that I originally scheduled, and get a bit of data from it which I will then output saying that it was unable to execute. This would then, later, be used by the application to attempt to execute it when the application then starts back up.

Comment: Actually, the javadoc you point to says it returns a list of Runnables.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: The method specification is List<Runnable>, but the actual text of the shutdownNow() method says it's ScheduledFuture's. I'm guessing that it really means RunnableScheduledFuture since the return type must be a Runnable, but even with that interface, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the original object that I scheduled :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to get info about objects submitted to an executor is to maintain a pointer to the original objects (be they extensions to Callable, Runnable, etc).  After you call shutdownNow(), and take into account the Runnable's returned by that which were **awaiting** execution, you can use that to prune your original list of objects and just interrogate the ones that were actually run.

Comment: Hmm...so if I were to add a Map which contains a reference to the Runnable's I schedule with the Future object, and at the end of the run() method remove it from that Map, that should work right. And so when I call shutdownNow(), I then iterate over the Map and query the Future to see if it completed or not. Does that sound workable? Or am I going too complicated?

Comment: You should be careful with memory leaks with this approach, I suggest removing from the collection as soon as possible. Depends on how many task you will submit before shutdown.

Comment: It may make sense, although if I put the removal code in a finally block at the very end of my run() method, I'll be safe in avoiding memory leaks.

Comment: If you need to interrogate objects that have been run, it would seem to me you have no choice but to keep pointers to them.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to present the information to the user, the simplest approach might be to implement a meaningful `toString()` method for the `Runnable`s you'r scheduling. Then you can simply iterate the list the `Executor` gives you and log what you get.

*But the sad truth* is that your original objects get wrapped by the `Executor`, though. Then you would need to keep a list of what you pass to the `Executor` manually and let the `Runnable`s remove themselves from this list when they get executed. Obviously, you would need to use a thread-safe list for this purpose.

Comment: The problem is that I don't appear (haven't actually run code though) to get the original Runnable's that I schedule back, so I can't do that. I'll need to keep a list, as you and Kelly Vista recommend.

Comment: They get wrapped in a FutureTask, which wraps them in an AbstractQueuedSynchronizer, which wraps them in a Callable.  They are pretty darn hard to get at :)

Comment: Yea, very annoying for doing something like this. Which it kinda confuses me. Wouldn't it be a common thing to want to be able to get the original object that you schedule when handed a List from shutdownNow()? That's what I'd expect, which is how ThreadPoolExecutor seems to do it.